# Errors with installing SNA packages

Tags: eclipse, r

I've been trying to install SNA packages but i always get the next errors,

```
> install.packages("sna")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/rvaca/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/sna_2.2-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 273329 bytes (266 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 266 Kb


The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7iF3Qz/downloaded_packages’
> library(sna)
starting httpd help server ... done
Error in attr(helpObj, "call") <- this.call : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘sna’
> library("sna")
Error in attr(helpObj, "call") <- this.call : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘sna’
> library('sna')
Error in attr(helpObj, "call") <- this.call : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘sna’
```

What happened? Thanks in advance

vacing

Comment: Can you add the output from the `sessionInfo()` command to your question? That might help people diagnose your problem

Comment: Just to add, I get the same error message:Error in attr(helpObj, "call") <- this.call : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
In addition: Warning message:
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'sna'
 when loading on my windows machine, but only using Eclipse IDE.  When I load R directly, I don't get this error.  I even tried using the help options described in the comment below, still getting the error through eclipse.  Not sure if that helps the more savvy people figure it out.

Comment: Also, from sessionInfo(), I don't think I can post the whole thing in a comment, but the one part that showed sna was: loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.14.1   rj.gd_1.0.3-3 sna_2.2-0

Comment: @Wine, are you the same user as user1310873? Than I suggest you merge the accounts. In addition, just edit the sessionInfo into the post.

Comment: No - I'm a different user - just wanted to note that I also had the problem - quite similar, it seems, as we are both using Eclipse/StatET when we have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When loading the `sna` package using `library(sna)` or `require(sna)`, the function `.First.lib()` is (still) called. This function is now among the defunct functions in the base package (see `?.First.lib`), but that's beside the point.

Looking at the source files for sna, `.First.lib()` is defined in the file zzz.R and contains the line

```
ehelp <- help(package="sna")$info[[1]].
```

This does not work well if `getOption("help_type")` is not `"text"`. You could, therefore, try setting this option before loading the package to see if that works.

```
options(help_type="text")
library(sna)
```

Does this still produce an error?

**EDIT**

Since the above still gives an error, and since the package has properties that are being phased out (i.e., no namespace, and using `.First.lib()`), I would recommend contacting the package's maintainer (perhaps with a reference to this question on SO):

```
packageDescription("sna")$Maintainer
```

Again, my suspicion is that the problem lies in creating the object `ehelp` in the `.First.lib()` function, which is called since there is no package namespace specified.

Comment: :( yes it does, > options(help_type="text")
> library(sna)
starting httpd help server ... done
Error in attr(helpObj, "call") <- this.call : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘sna’

Comment: @user, This seems to be a good reason to contact the package's maintainer - please see the **EDIT** above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the result of sessionInfo(), (I forgot to comment that i runs it into Eclipse)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Cairo_1.5-1    igraph_0.5.5-4 rj_1.0.3-7    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rj.gd_1.0.3-3 sna_2.2-0     tools_2.14.2
```

Comment: Please do not add exrra information as an answer, but edit your post to add the sessionInfo.